# how can i get value from dynamically generated edittexts?

Tags: android

I am getting only a single value.how can i get data from all of the editText which i have created dynamically so that i can pass all editText data using comma  after every editText .

Here is my code:

```
Diagnolist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText ed;
            Integer count = 1;
            final List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                ed = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                allEds.add(ed);
                ed.setId(i);
                ed.setHint("add diagonis");
                ed.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                addDiagnosis.addView(ed);
            }
Toast_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String[] strings = new String[(allEds.size())];
    String st = "";



    for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
        strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
        st = strings[i]+"," +st;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, st, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do changes as per below code.

```
final List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
```

declare above list after class define.

```
Diagnolist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText ed;
        Integer count = 1;


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            ed = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            allEds.add(ed);
            ed.setId(i);
            ed.setHint("add diagonis");
            ed.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            addDiagnosis.addView(ed);
        }
Toast_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
      String[] strings = new String[(allEds.size())];
      String st = "";
      for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
           strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
           st += strings[i]+",";
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, st, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  }
 });
}
  });
```

Comment: edittext1 =aaaa   editext2:bbbbb and i am getting   as aaaa first and then aaaa,bbbbb

Comment: I updated my code.please try above code st += strings[i]+",";

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, so correct me if i am wrong. I think you want to get a comma-separated String of all values.
I would just change the onClick to following:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String st;

    for(EditText ed : allEds){
        st += "," + ed.getText().toString();
    }

    st = st.substring(1); // cut leading comma
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, st, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: The String st contains all values as comma separated string. you have set Integer count = 1; in your code so you only have one EditText

Comment: Then try what Vasant said and define your list after the class definition